# Opening facebook profile page in facebook native app from my android app

Tags: android, facebook

I'm trying to open a specific profile page from my android app, in the native facebook app. I've seen many answers about this topic, but none of them worked for me currently (maybe because some new versions)

Right now, I'm trying to open it like that:

```
 public static Intent getFacebookIntent(PackageManager pm, String url ,String fbID) {
        Intent intent;
        try {
            int versionCode = pm.getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0).versionCode;
            boolean activated =  pm.getApplicationInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0).enabled;
            if(activated){
                if ((versionCode >= 3002850)) {
                    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://facewebmodal/f?href=" + url));
                    return intent;

                } else {
                    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://page/" + fbID));
                    return intent;
                }
            }else{
                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                return intent;
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            return intent;
        }
    }
```

where fbID its the user id, and url is the "link" from user graph request.
I've tried to change the url, to a specific url like
"https://www.facebook.com/some_user_name" but not luck.

the result of that code, is that the facebook app opens and crashes.
I do able to open it with webpage link.

Thanks